# Delegates issue in source controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) which helps a lot a beginner like me.
There are 2 screens, Players (which displays a list of players) and PlayerDetails(which displays details about a player and also allows adding a new one)

This is the code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PlayerDetailsViewController.h"

@interface PlayersViewController : UITableViewController<PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *players;
@end

#import "Player.h"
#import "PlayerCell.h"
#import "PlayersViewController.h"

@class PlayerDetailsViewController;

@interface PlayersViewController ()


@end

@implementation PlayersViewController

@synthesize players;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.players count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PlayerCell *cell = (PlayerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
    Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = player.name;
    cell.gameLabel.text = player.game;
    cell.ratingImageView.image = [self imageForRating:player.rating];
    return cell;
}

- (UIImage *)imageForRating:(int)rating
{
    switch (rating)
    {
        case 1: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"1StarSmall.png"];
        case 2: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"2StarsSmall.png"];
        case 3: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"3StarsSmall.png"];
        case 4: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"4StarsSmall.png"];
        case 5: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"5StarsSmall.png"];
    }
    return nil;
}



/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.players removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}



/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPlayer"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PlayerDetailsViewController *playerDetailsViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        playerDetailsViewController.delegate=self;
    }
}

-(void) playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void)playerDetailsViewController: PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller didAddPlayer:(Player *)player
{
    [self.players addObject:player];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.players count] - 1 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Player.h"

@class PlayerDetailsViewController;

@protocol PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>
-(void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:(PlayerDetailsViewController*) controller;
-(void)playerDetailsViewController:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller didAddPlayer:(Player *)player;
@end

@interface PlayerDetailsViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailLabel;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@property(weak, nonatomic) id<PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

#import "PlayerDetailsViewController.h"

@class Player;

@interface PlayerDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayerDetailsViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        [self.nameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}



- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = self.nameTextField.text;
    player.game = @"Chess";
    player.rating = 1;
    [self.delegate playerDetailsViewController:self didAddPlayer:player];
}
@end
```

Issue:
In PlayersViewController.m,  on the following method:

```
-(void)playerDetailsViewController:PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller didAddPlayer:(Player *)player
```

I get the following error messages

1. Expected method body
2. Use of undeclared identifier player

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an opening parenthesis:

```
-(void)playerDetailsViewController: PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller ...
```

should be:

```
-(void)playerDetailsViewController:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller ...
```